# Custom action bar title without icon when using tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I'm trying to set the color of my custom action bar from black to silver. The following images show what my app looks like at the moment. I'm trying to get rid of the black bar on the second image. I'm using the following code:

final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: post the code of `R.layout.action_bar`

Comment: @mmlooloo

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
       android:text="CONNECT!"
       android:textSize="26dp"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>
</RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that I left this question high and dry as I was in a hurry to finish this project. I ended up fixing the issue by using the [AccentFragmentActivity.java](https://github.com/negusoft/holoaccent/blob/master/HoloAccentExample/src/com/negusoft/holoaccent/example/activity/AccentFragmentActivity.java). I had put in an issue [here](https://github.com/negusoft/holoaccent/issues/38) on Github. Since others weren't able to replicate this I think there was just some setting off that I couldn't locate, but if anyone runs to this in the future then maybe try using AccentFragmentActivity!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get rid of the black bar on the second image

change `android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"` to `android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"`

Update:

this is your icon that you put so remove that:

```
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I got excited because I thought that would do it. Unfortunately it did not. :/ I'm going to try switching from a RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout. At this point, I'm trying anything. --- Edit: That did not work either.

Comment: try clean and rebuild because it must work, at the end if it wont post your style.

Comment: I tried a Clean and Rebuild to no avail. Here is my style to not show my icon. The drawable I'm using below is a 1x1 transparent pixel. `<style name="GreenAccentTheme" parent="Theme.HoloAccent">
        <item name="accentColor">#80ff00</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/icon_title</item>
        <item name="icon">@drawable/icon_title</item>
    </style>`

Answer (score 0):

use this, this will solve ur problem

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.demo);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Does it matter which order you set these flags? For instance, can I set my custom view and then call the flags?

Comment: i tried the above code with your layout( that u posted), it worked in my case, i also tried to rearrange the lines ( i set the view and then the  custom flag) and then also it worked and yes.. in ur code i didnt use the margin_left value

Comment: may be.. because i didnt set any specific style for the action bar.. iam using the default holo dark